# Dynamically Delete Elements WIthin an R loop

Tags: list, r, for-loop, foreach, dataframe

Ok guys, as requested, I will add more info so that you understand why a simple vector operation is not possible. It's not easy to explain in few words but let's see. I have a huge amount of points over a 2D space. 
I divide my space in a grid with a given resolution,say, 100m. The main loop that I am not sure if it's mandatory or not (any alternative is welcomed) is to go through EACH cell/pixel that contains at least 2 points (right now I am using the method quadratcount within the package spatstat). 
Inside this loop, thus for each one of this non empty cells, I have to find and keep only a maximum of 10 Male-Female pairs that are within 3 meters from each other. The 3-meter buffer can be done using the "disc" function within spatstat. To select points falling inside a buffer you can use the method pnt.in.poly within the SDMTools package. All that because pixels have a maximum capacity that cannot be exceeded. Since in each cell there can be hundreds or thousands of points I am trying to find a smart way to use another loop/similar method to:
1)go trough each point at a time 2)create a buffer a select points with different sex 3)Save the closest Male-Female (0-1) pair in another dataframe (called new_colonies) 4)Remove those points from the dataframe so that it shrinks and I don't have to consider them anymore 5) as soon as that new dataframe reaches 10 rows stop everything and go to the next cell (thus skipping all remaining points. Here is the code that I developed to be run within each cell (right now it takes too long):

head(df,20):

```
 X       Y Sex ID
2  583058.2 2882774   1  1
3  582915.6 2883378   0  2
4  582592.8 2883297   1  3
5  582793.0 2883410   1  4
6  582925.7 2883397   1  5
7  582934.2 2883277   0  6
8  582874.7 2883336   0  7
9  583135.9 2882773   1  8
10 582955.5 2883306   1  9
11 583090.2 2883331   0 10
12 582855.3 2883358   1 11
13 582908.9 2883035   1 12
14 582608.8 2883715   0 13
15 582946.7 2883488   1 14
16 582749.8 2883062   0 15
17 582906.4 2883317   0 16
18 582598.9 2883390   0 17
19 582890.2 2883413   0 18
20 582752.8 2883361   0 19
21 582953.1 2883230   1 20
```

Inside each cell I must run something according to what I explained above..

`for(i in 1:dim(df)[1])`{

```
new_colonies <- data.frame(ID1=0,ID2=0,X=0,Y=0) 

discbuff <- disc(radius, centre=c(df$X[i], df$Y[i])) 

#define the points and polygon
pnts = cbind(df$X[-i],df$Y[-i])
polypnts = cbind(x = discbuff$bdry[[1]]$x, y = discbuff$bdry[[1]]$y)
out = pnt.in.poly(pnts,polypnts)
out$ID <- df$ID[-i]

if (any(out$pip == 1)) {

pnt.inBuffID <- out$ID[which(out$pip == 1)] 
cond <- df$Sex[i] != df$Sex[pnt.inBuffID]

if (any(cond)){

eucdist <- sqrt((df$X[i] - df$X[pnt.inBuffID][cond])^2 + (df$Y[i] - df$Y[pnt.inBuffID][cond])^2)

IDvect <- pnt.inBuffID[cond]
new_colonies_temp <- data.frame(ID1=df$ID[i], ID2=IDvect[which(eucdist==min(eucdist))], 
                 X=(df$X[i] + df$X[pnt.inBuffID][cond][which(eucdist==min(eucdist))]) / 2, 
                 Y=(df$Y[i] + df$Y[pnt.inBuffID][cond][which(eucdist==min(eucdist))]) / 2)

new_colonies <- rbind(new_colonies,new_colonies_temp)

if (dim(new_colonies)[1] == maxdensity) break

}
}
}

new_colonies <- new_colonies[-1,]
```

Any help appreciated!
Thanks
Francesco

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to give us a reproducible example, e.g. by using `dput(head(df,10))`. Besides, it would be nice to know something about that certain condition, cause maybe you do not even need to loop but can solve it the vectorized way.

Comment: I will specify all I need to do with relative code as soon as it lets me asnwer my own question and post here...check it soon and if you can help me that would be great!

Comment: @Francesco - you can (and should) simply edit your question!

Comment: @Tommy...thanks, I am new here so I did not know I could edit my post.

Comment: You should state how you select which 10 you're going to keep... first 10?, 10 closest to each other?, random 10... etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case I wouldn't worry about deleting the points as you go, skipping is the critical thing.  I also wouldn't make up a new data.frame piece by piece like you seem to be doing.  Both of those things slow you down a lot.  Having a selection vector is much more efficient (perhaps part of the data.frame, that you set to FALSE beforehand).

```
df$sel <- FALSE
```

Now, when you go through you set df$sel to TRUE for each item you want to keep. Just  skip to the next cell when you find your 10.  Deleting values as you go will be time consuming and memory intensive, as will slowly growing a new data.frame.  When you're all done going through them then you can just select your data based on the selection column.

```
df <- df[ df$sel, ]
```

(or maybe make a copy of the data.frame at that point)

You also might want to use the `dist` function to calculate a matrix of distances.

from `?dist`

"This function computes and returns the distance matrix computed by using the specified distance measure to compute the distances between the rows of a data matrix."

Comment: I will post my answer soon with all explanation of what I am trying to do..please check it if you can...Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot...I will try that. So basically using rbind to build a dataframe a little bit at a time is time consuming and slow in R. So you are saying that I cannot get rid of the 2 for loops (one to go through each grid cell and one (code above) to go through each points within that cell....? I have another question regarding this dataframe stack procedure but I will post it later on in another section.

Comment: It's best to keep your outer loop.  Your inner loop might be able to be mostly vectorized.  Did you look at dist?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are doing something sufficiently complicated that the for-loop is actually required...

So here's one rather simple approach: first just gather the rows to delete (or keep), and then delete the rows afterwards. Typically this will be much faster too since you don't modify the `data.frame` on each loop iteration.

```
df <- generateTheDataFrame()

keepRows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(df))
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  rows <- findRowsToDelete(df, df[i,]) 
  keepRows[rows] <- FALSE
}

# Delete afterwards
df <- df[keepRows, ]
```

...and if you really need to work on the shrunk data in each iteration, just change the for-loop part to:

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  if (keepRows[i]) {
      rows <- findRowsToDelete(df[keepRows, ], df[i,]) 
      keepRows[rows] <- FALSE
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if you have to run a loop on the rows to get the value that you'll check later for whether you want to keeping the row or not, it's best to do that check afterwards.  Either of these examples will add significantly more time to the loop than a subsequent vectorized selection will take.

Comment: @john - true, but only when it is feasible to do so. Without more information it's just another guess - although a good one ;-). Vectorization is great, but not always possible (conditional cumulative sums spring to mind).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on why you're looping.  If you could describe what kind of conditions you're checking there might be a nice vectorized way of doing it.

However as a very simple fix have you considered looping through the dataframe backwards?

Comment: Why would I loop backwards? Is that going to make it faster?

Comment: If you loop backwards and remove rows as you go it's not necessarily efficient but in this manner you don't skip rows.

Comment: But my question in that case would be, since a loop requires an index range, if I remove some rows during the loop am I going to receive an error that the index is out of range (since the dimension of the dataframe would change)?

Comment: Looping backwards would solve the problem with the dimension.  But it's all moot since if you're using R you really shouldn't be doing this through the use of loops.